# Mobile web on nokia devices not displaying centain elements

Tags: xhtml, mobile-website, nokiabrowser

So i have a site which is rendered with our in-house portal engine. It resizes images and adjusts style-sheets automatically in real-time.

Issue is that some html elements are inexplicably disappearing due to what only can be described as HTML compatibility. But the problem is not consistent. And only seems to be an issue on some nokia devices.

I have tried to install the Nokia Mobile Browser Emulator... but its the worst piece of software i have seen in my life... after 4 hours of installing and uninstalling different versions of JRE, i still can't get it to install.

EDIT: Problem now residing at http://wiseguy.mobi/?PageID=657

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have checked your site using [mobiReady](http://mobiready.com/results.jsp?uri=http://samen.itell.mobi/&locale=en_EN) and you should check your MIME-type. In mobile web are important those details

Comment: While stating the obvious is great. Did you find anything wrong with the MIME-type?

Comment: Your MIME type is text/html and you document is xml.
For XHTML-MP, the recommended MIME type is application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml or application/xhtml+xml. Unlike HTML, XHTML-MP should not be served as text/html.

I had this problem and changing the MIME type solved it. Mobile browser are more stricted.

Comment: Great, tx. My problem is that the html isn't entirely XHTML conpliant. And breaks completely if I set the mimetype to xhtml? any remidies for this? maybe a filter that'll fix any obvious mistakes. The content is user edited, and get allot of "<br>" in stead of "<br />".

Comment: Ok, so i have managed to correct the mime-type issue that you spoke about. Problem is Series 60 browsers seem to still arbitrarily chuck anything within a <form/>. There just doesn't seem to be any pattern. Problem page also verifies 100% on the W3C validator for XHTML MP 1.2?